# How do I upgrade my Dell XCD35 from 2.2 Froyo to 2.3 Gingerbread?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, zte-blade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

I'm not an expert in this, and need help. I have serious issues with the Froyo build and want to upgrade my brand new phone to Gingerbread. How can I do this?
It is not available as a standard upgrade through the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Root it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone).
2. Install Clockworkmod Recovery.

   1. Install [ROM Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager).
   2. Run it and select your device.
   3. Choose the "Flash Clockwork recovery" (or similar) option.
3. Install [a custom ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=909).

Note that doing this voids your warranty and may brick your device.  I highly recommend reading through the XDA forum (the last link above) so you get a good grasp of everything involved here.  In particular, a lot of the ROMs are for "GEN2 devices".  I don't know know if that's a hardware revision or a firmware version, or if there are any relevant differences between the Dell XCD35 and the ZTE Blade that you would need to account for before installing a Blade ROM.  **Edit:** See http://wiki.modaco.com/index.php/ZTE_Blade#What_different_Blade_versions_are_out_there.3F for some useful info, the rest of that wiki is useful too.

Comment: In that case, I'm going to read up and be thorough before I do it. Thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

Full guide to root & upgrate to 2.3 rom found on [android.modaco.com](http://android.modaco.com/topic/335781-22apr-guide-how-to-install-a-custom-rom-on-the-zte-u-v880-or-gen2-device/)